# Rename language after item is created

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm using sitecore 6.5 with two languages installed, en (default) and fr-CA. There are items in the tree with content in both en and fr-CA.

The problem is that the French url has 'fr-CA' in it and we want that to be 'fr', for example:

http://website.com/fr/page.aspx instead of http://website.com/fr-CA/page.aspx

I tried renaming the language from 'fr-CA' to 'fr' and that fixed the url but the content still points to the old language 'fr-CA', so the item shows three languages: en, fr and fr-CA. It's not recognizing the name change.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Tarek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have created `fr-CA` versions of your items which cannot be fixed by renaming the language .. you can now make a `fr` version but, like you are seeing, this means there are now 3 possible versions.

One suggestion is to leave the languages in Sitecore alone and alter how links are served and processed instead.

You would probably need to look at adding your own method into the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline in Sitecore. This would follow the `LanguageResolver` entry. You can then parse the `RawUrl` and set `Sitecore.Context.Langauge' to French if the first element in it matched`/fr/`.

**Extremely quick & dirty example:**

```
public class MyLanguageResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        string languageText = WebUtil.ExtractLanguageName(args.Context.Request.RawUrl);

        if(languageText == "fr")
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage("fr-CA");
        }
    }
}
```

You would probably also have to override the `LinkProvider` in the `<linkManager>` section of the web.config to format your URLs when they are resolved by Sitecore.

**Another extremely quick & dirty example:**

```
public class MyLinkProvider : LinkProvider
{
    public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, UrlOptions options)
    {
        var url = base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
        url = url.Replace("/fr-CA/", "/fr/");
        return url;
    }    
}
```

Another way (slightly more long-winded as it will need to be executed via a script) is to copy the data from the `fr-CA` version to the `fr` version and then delete the fr-CA version of each item.

**Rough helper method that encompasses what you're trying to do**

```
    private void CopyLanguage(ID id, Language sourceLanguage, Language destinationLanguage)
    {
        var master = Database.GetDatabase("master");

        var sourceLanguageItem = master.GetItem(id, sourceLanguage);
        var destinationLanguageItem = master.GetItem(id, destinationLanguage);

        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            destinationLanguageItem.Editing.BeginEdit();

            //for each field in source, create in destination if it does not exist
            foreach (Field sf in sourceLanguageItem.Fields)
            {
                if (sf.Name.Contains("_")) continue;

                destinationLanguageItem.Fields[sf.Name].Value = sf.Value;
            }

            destinationLanguageItem.Editing.AcceptChanges();

            ////Remove the source language version
            ItemManager.RemoveVersions(sourceLanguageItem,sourceLanguage, SecurityCheck.Disable);
        }
    }
```

Another way to update the languages on your content items is:

1. Export the fr-CA language to a `.xml` file (Using the Control Panel)
2. In the .xml file replace all  and  tags with the  and
3. Rename fr-CA language in the master database to the fr
4. Import language from the .xml file
5. Run Clean Up Databases task (from the Control Panel)

Also you can create a sql script that will change fr-CA language with the fr for all records in the UnversionedFields and VersionedFields tables.

If you need any more information or examples please let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the details. I ended up leaving the 'fr-CA' and creating my own language resolver and link manager as you suggested above. Was a bit tricky to handle the different languages and language parameter but got it to working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to rename a language while retaining the content. I decided to migrate content from one language to another by using Unicorn:

1: Create a predicate telling Unicorn to track all of your content. In my case:

```
            <include name="site content" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/mySite" />
```

2. Reserialize the content, writing it to disk as YML files
3. Using a tool that can perform a find & replace in multiple files at once, such as Notepad++, replace all instances of "Language: fr-CA" with "Language: fr" in your yml files.
4. Run a Unicorn Sync

You will find that all of your content is now associated with the "fr" language instead of "fr-CA".